# PhpRunner: Getting error in - classes/controls/ViewFileField.php on line 60... How to solve it?

Tags: php, file-upload

We are using an admin panel which is create using PhpRUnner 10.3 (by a developer on Fiverr), and it was working just great on our old VPS which has Php 5.6. But just yesterday we switched to a new hosting company called GoDaddy. On GoDaddy the Php version was 7.4 I changed it to 5.6 but still the error occures.

After uploading the admin panel to GoDaddy we are getting error as follows:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
> '/home/g6oss6ljbwlx/public_html/admin/classes/uploadhandler.php'
> (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php')
> in
> /home/g6oss6ljbwlx/public_html/admin/classes/controls/ViewFileField.php
> on line 60

The developer is not answering our query any more as he had completed out project 6 months back.

Can this problem be solved?

If yes please help.

Comment: You need to check in Code If any Path's defined statically. Or it require debug the code. It require more code to understand. It's good If you share file code ViewFileField.php on line 60 for better understand

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

The file (`uploadhandler.php`) being referred to in `ViewFileField.php` has case difference. I copied the file `UploadHandler.php` and **renamed** it to `uploadhandler.php` and now the admin panel has started working!!

I am still puzzled as to why it was working properly in our old server and giving errors in GoDaddy server.

Will check into that when I get time.